# Db2 query while fetching data from 3 table

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have the following table layout

**Table a**

```
Teacher Students
Mohan pankaj
Mohan sudeepa
Mohan sujitra
Mohan Sumit
```

**Table b (semester 1 marks)**

```
Pankaj Maths 50
Pankaj English 40
Pankaj Physics 60
Sudeepa Chemisty 40
Sujitra Physic 10
Sujitra English 40
Sujitra Hindi 70
```

**Table c (semester 2 marks)**

```
Pankaj Chemistry 50
Pankaj English 40
Pankaj Physics 60
Sudeepa Science 40
Sujitra Physic 10
Sujitra Maths 40
Sujitra Hindi 70
```

**I want output as :-**

```
hindi 140.00
maths 40.00
physics 10.00
science 40.00
chemistry 40.00
english 40.00
physics 10.00
```

**I wrote the query**

```
select subject,sum(marks) from sample.b where
student in ( select student from sample.a where teacher='mohan')
group by subject

union all
select subject,sum(marks) from sample.c
where student in ( select student from sample.test where teacher='mohan')
group by subject
```

**I am getting the result as**

```
hindi 70.00
maths 40.00
physics 10.00
science 40.00
chemistry 40.00
english 40.00
hindi 70.00
physics 10.00
```

****ISSUE****  `Same subjects marks are not adding up`..

Comment: As a side note, your DB design is problematic - are you planning on adding a table for _every_ different semester?  You'd be better off having a single 'Class_Taken' table (or similar), with a couple of extra columns added for school-year and semester.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Your query might look like

```
SELECT s.subject, s1.marks sem1_marks, s2.marks sem2_marks
FROM
(
  SELECT b.subject 
    FROM b JOIN a 
      ON b.student = a.students
   WHERE a.teacher = 'Mohan'
   UNION 
  SELECT c.subject 
    FROM c JOIN a 
      ON c.student = a.students
   WHERE a.teacher = 'Mohan'
) s 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT b.subject, SUM(b.marks) marks
    FROM b JOIN a 
      ON b.student = a.students
   WHERE a.teacher = 'Mohan'
   GROUP BY b.subject
) s1 ON s.subject = s1.subject 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT c.subject, SUM(c.marks) marks
    FROM c JOIN a 
      ON c.student = a.students
   WHERE a.teacher = 'Mohan'
   GROUP BY c.subject
) s2 ON s.subject = s2.subject
```

Output:

```
|   SUBJECT | SEM1_MARKS | SEM2_MARKS |
---------------------------------------
| Chemistry |         40 |         50 |
|   English |         80 |         40 |
|     Hindi |         70 |         70 |
|     Maths |         50 |         40 |
|   Physics |         70 |         70 |
|   Science |     (null) |         40 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f64ef/8)** demo (again SQL Server but should work in DB2).

**Original answer to original question:**
You need to `UNION ALL` two datasets (either aggregated or not) in inner select first and then apply an aggregate `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` in outer select.

```
SELECT subject, SUM(marks) marks
FROM
(
  SELECT student, subject, marks 
    FROM b JOIN a 
      ON b.student = a.students
   WHERE a.teacher = 'Mohan'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT student, subject, marks 
    FROM c JOIN a 
      ON c.student = a.students
   WHERE a.teacher = 'Mohan'
) q
 GROUP BY subject
```

Output:

```
|   SUBJECT | MARKS |
---------------------
| Chemistry |    90 |
|   English |   120 |
|     Hindi |   140 |
|     Maths |    90 |
|   Physics |   140 |
|   Science |    40 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f64ef/1)** demo (SQL Server). *But I believe it should work the same in DB2.*

Comment: I am sorry...There is a slight change in requirement..I want output assubject   sem1 marks     sem2 marks
chemistry  90             50
english    80             40
physics    70             70  
Hindi      70             70
Science                   40
Maths                     40

Comment: I am sorry...There is a slight change in requirement..I want output assubject   sem1 marks     sem2 marks
chemistry  90             50
english    80             40
physics    70             70  
Hindi      70             70
Science                   40
Maths                     40 In subjects I need all the list of subjects and need to add up all marks of sem1 and sem 2

Comment: @coolpinky That is a **considerable** change of requirements. Just so you know it's not encouraged to do such things (ask one question and then after you've got an answer to your original question change it) on SO. Anyway see updated answer for a solution to your problem.

Comment: @coolpinky Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you've asked for, by segregating the grades into separate columns.

```
Select subject, sum(s1mark) sem1tot, sum(s2mark) sem2tot
From ( select subject, mark as s1mark, 0 as s2mark
         From b join a  on a.student=b.student and a.teacher='Mohan'
       UNION
       select subject, 0 as s1mark, mark as s2mark
         From b join a  on a.student=b.student and a.teacher='Mohan'
     )
group by subject
order by subject
```